# Comparing data to a mapping file in R

Tags: r, compare, mapping, data-science

I am quite new in R and need help at a project for work.
My company is switching from single role assignment to multi-role assigment in our system.
The mapping file for two roles could look like this:

| old role | new role |
| --- | --- |
| teacher | literature expert |
| teacher | caretaker |
| teacher | nice adult |
| janitor | cleaner |
| janitor | plumber |

My task is to write a script which will check if everything was migrated correctly: every employee that used to be assigned „teacher“ should now be assigned „literature expert“, „caretaker“ and „nice adult“ instead.

So far I did a full outer join with the data from the old system with the old roles and the new system with the new roles.
I also have an Excel Sheet with the mapping data, consisting of the columns „old_role“ and „new_role“.

`df <- merge(x = newdata, y = olddata, by „employee_ID, all = TRUE)`

Now I have a data frame like this:

| employee_id | old_role | new_role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | teacher | literature expert |
| 1 | teacher | caretaker |
| 1 | teacher | nice adult |
| 2 | teacher | caretaker |
| 2 | teacher | nice adult |
| 3 | janitor | cleaner |
| 3 | janitor | plumber |
| 4 | janitor | cleaner |
| 4 | janitor | plumber |
| 4 | janitor | nice adult |

Employee 1 and 3 are migrated correctly. Employee 2 misses one role, employee 4 has been falsely assigned a role.

Now I am not sure how to continue.
I need R to iterate through every employee and check if the new roles are assigned correctly according to the old role and print feedback "ok" or "not ok" per employee.
I thought about creating a new column in my df containing this output, but I am not sure if this would work, because it should relate to multiple rows - only if every necessary role is assigned and none additionally added, it should print "ok".
An output in the Terminal is also fine. I am not picky about the format.

What's the best way to compare my data to the mapping data?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Could you post more sample data? And preferably your ultimate desired output

Comment: @Chamkrai I added more information to the question - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
rules <- tribble(~old_role,~new_role,
"teacher"   ,"literature expert",
"teacher"   ,"caretaker",
"teacher"   ,"nice adult",
"janitor"   ,"cleaner",
"janitor"   ,"plumber")


rules_smry <- group_by(rules,old_role) |> 
  summarise(nr_required=list(sort(new_role))) 

to_check <- tibble::tribble(
  ~employee_id, ~old_role,           ~new_role,
            1L, "teacher", "literature expert",
            1L, "teacher",         "caretaker",
            1L, "teacher",        "nice adult",
            2L, "teacher",         "caretaker",
            2L, "teacher",        "nice adult",
            3L, "janitor",           "cleaner",
            3L, "janitor",           "plumber",
            4L, "janitor",           "cleaner",
            4L, "janitor",           "plumber",
            4L, "janitor",        "nice adult"
  )

group_by(to_check,employee_id,old_role) |> 
  summarise(nr_actuals=list(sort(new_role))) |>
              ungroup() |>  
  left_join(rules_smry) |> rowwise() |> 
  mutate(status = case_when(identical(nr_actuals,nr_required)~"Perfect",
                            length(nr_actuals)>length(nr_required) ~ "more than needed",
                            length(nr_required)>length(nr_actuals) ~ "less than needed"),
         diff_1 = paste0(setdiff(nr_actuals,nr_required),collapse="; "),
         diff_2 = paste0(setdiff(nr_required,nr_actuals),collapse="; "))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Everything is running smoothly until the left join. An Error occurs then: "Error in left-join(): 'by' must be supplied when 'x' and 'y' have no common variables" - any idea how to fix this? Is there also a way to refer to the columns in my mapping df when creating the tribble instead of pasting everything into the console? I am handling so much data, the effort can't be done with pasting

Comment: 1) In my example the join combines the data with the rules on the data by the `old_role` variable which they have in common. What do you have ? What you presented implied you had old_role 2) yes, refer to your data in the normal way, thats impossible for me without a tribble construction, becaues I dont have your data ...

Comment: 1. so you want to merge rules and to check? correct me if I am wrong, but aren't you joining to_check and rules_smry? the latter looks more like a vector than a df (1 var, 1 obs)

Comment: whats the clarification that you need ? you are right that i join to_check and rules_smry; the join occurs over the old_role variable that they have in common. rules_smry is certainly a data.frame in my example and not a vector ... I dont know what to say about that to assist you.

Comment: okay, I think I found the problem. rules_smry is in fact a data.frame, but it has only one column called "nr_required" with one obs - apparently the vector of all the new roles of rules... any idea what went wrong? thank you a lot for helping me out, I am super confused

Comment: I'm limited in how I can help you based on the lack of information about your true scenario. Lets recap ;  You provided an example, and I provided a solution that works for the example. Therefore you will have to think about how your example is different from your true challenge; so as to either find your own solution; or repose the question with an updated example that a stackoverflower could try to help you solve.